# MySQL: What kind of data could lead to a large BinLOG

Tags: mysql

I try to migrate a table from node 1 to node 2. The table has 22 million rows, full of string characters and some empty columns filled with NULL.

According to `information_schema.TABLES`, the table size is only **12GB**, but the migration generates almost **40GB** binlog on node2. Why is the size of binlog 3 times larger than the data inserted? What may result in extra space in binlog?

The MySQL version is 5.7. Any help is apprecited.

Comment: How exactly did you migrate the database?

Comment: hi @Kondybas  I used the migrate tool in SQLYOG.

Comment: Check the "server_id" on each machine.  If they are the same, you have a loop.